# При импорте dll выдает ошибку WinError 193

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, dll, x86-64

Пытаюсь импортировать библиотеку которая присутствует в System32 так-же выполнял команду regsvr32 в cmd запущенной от имени администратора. При попытке импортировать вот эти кодом:

```py
from ctypes.util import find_library
from ctypes import *
import json

tdjson_path = find_library("tdjson")
print(tdjson_path)
tdjson = CDLL(tdjson_path)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
tdjson.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mihail\Desktop\Пересылка\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    tdjson = CDLL(tdjson_path)
  File "C:\Users\Mihail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32
```

Прошу обратить внимание что `print(tdjson_path)` выводит tdjson.dll это значит что команда regsvr32 выполнена верно а также этот dll присутствует в папке System32

Версия Python `Python 3.7.8`

Comment: Проблему решил надо было запустить через 64bit python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если dll 64bit то и python должен быть 64bit